# Invalid content was found starting with element 'jaxrs:servicebeans'"

Tags: java, xml, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to run a JAX-RS service. While trying to start Tomcat server, I am getting an error "**Invalid content was found starting with element 'jaxrs:servicebeans'**"

Detailed error is -

*
*Invalid content was found starting with element 'jaxrs:servicebeans'. One of '{"http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":executor, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":features, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":binding, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":dataBinding, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":inInterceptors, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":inFaultInterceptors, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":invoker, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":serviceFactories, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":outInterceptors, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":outFaultInterceptors, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":properties, **"http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":serviceBeans**, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":modelBeans, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":model, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":providers, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":extensionMappings, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":languageMappings, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":schemaLocations, "http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs":resourceComparator}' is expected.*
*

My spring configuration file is -

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:addressing="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:beans="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/beans"
    xmlns:configuration="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:parameterized-types="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/parameterized-types"
    xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:webservice="http://sf.icptp.springextensions/schema/webservice" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/ws/addressing.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/beans http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/cxf-beans.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/parameterized-types http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/parameterized-types.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
        http://sf.icptp.springextensions/schema/webservice http://sf.icptp.springextensions/schema/webservice/webservice.xsd" >

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <bean id="order" class="com.example.rest.OrderInfoImpl" />

    <jaxrs:server address="/" id="connectionService">
        <jaxrs:servicebeans>
            <ref bean="order"></ref>
        </jaxrs:servicebeans>
        <jaxrs:extensionmappings>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" ></entry>
        </jaxrs:extensionmappings>
    </jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

I am unable to figure out the reason, why it does not recognize the "**jaxrs:servicebeans**" tag inside the **jaxrs:server** tag. I am not sure if it is a problem with the version of **cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs**; although I did try with version 2.5.2 and 2.7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is case sensitive. Replace servicebeans to serviceBeans.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the answer was in the error logs itself where it said what it is expecting, clearly outlining the mismatch of the text.